# Function that return me the previous day

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-manipulation

Can you help me with this problem? I tried to make a function that receives a parameter of type `Date` e.g. 12.11.2020. I want it to return the previous day.

```js
function getPreviousDay(d) {
  var dateObj = new Date(d);
  var previousDay = dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() - 1);
  return previousDay;
}

console.log(getPreviousDay(new Date())); //1606809601830
```

But as you see, the function returns: 1606809601830, I don't know why.
Thank you, guys!

Comment: It is a date, but as a timestamp, not a human-readable date. You need to format it as one. Also, you pass `new Date()` to your function, so it receives a Date object, and the first thing you do is to `new Date(d)` it, which gives `new Date( new Date() )`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple ES6 one-liner would be :

```js
const getPreviousDay = d => d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1) && d

console.log(getPreviousDay(new Date()));
```

This function changes the day of the `Date` object you pass it, and returns it. No need to create an intermediary one.

Typescript version (with type checking, to make sure you always pass it a Date object, and not a string) :

```
const getPreviousDay = (d:Date): Date => d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1) && d
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to return the result of [`Date.prototype.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/setDate) which is the date in milliseconds, you want to return the mutated `dateObj`

```js
function getPreviousDay(d) {
  var dateObj = new Date(d);
  dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() - 1);
  return dateObj ;
}

console.log(getPreviousDay(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code return like this yesterday date(1.12.2020).

```js
function getPreviousDay(d) {
  var dateObj = new Date(d);
  dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate()-1);
  return dateObj.getDate() + '.' + (dateObj.getMonth()+1) + '.' + dateObj.getFullYear();
}

console.log(getPreviousDay(new Date()));
```